# Why is my answer on this integral wrong?

Tags: integration

I understand that the question was actually a straightforward u sub, but I didn’t notice it on the test and did it a different way. I don’t see why my answer is wrong. I can’t find the error in my work, but I know the answer is wrong (I graphed it).[image][image]

Also, sorry for not using Latex.

Comment: Is this $$\int\frac{x}{x^4+1}dx$$?

Comment: Your answer is correct.$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac12\arctan{(x\sqrt{2}-1)}-\frac12\arctan{(x\sqrt{2}+1)}\right)=\frac{x}{x^4+1}$$

Comment: This leads to the interesting problem: use trig identities to prove $$\arctan \left( {x}^{2} \right)/2 -\pi/4=\arctan \left( x\sqrt 
{2}-1 \right)/2 -\arctan \left( x\sqrt {2}+1 \right)/2 $$

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know about trig, but it's pretty straightforward using complex numbrers (although I guess I'm still using trig).